# Phaser.js delete object in group during forEach loop

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to destroy an object after it passes a certain x value.
The objects are part of a phaser group called balls.
In my update loop, I have this line of code:

```
balls.forEach(updateBalls, null, true);
```

Here is the updateBalls function:

```
function updateBalls(ball) {
  if (ball.x > 800) {
    ball.destroy();
  }
}
```

The problem is that deleting the object during the loop messes up the loop, this is the error I get:

> TypeError: this.children[i] is undefined

I tried to push each of the balls to an array and then destroying each ball like this.

```
function updateBalls(ball) {
  if (ball.x > 800) {
    ballsToDestroy.push(ball);
  }
}
```

Then in the update loop:

```
balls.forEach(updateBalls, null, true);
for (x = 0; x < ballsToDestroy.length; balls++) {
    ballsToDestroy[x].destroy();
}
```

This gave me some odd bugs though.
It works if I use ball.kill(), but that will eventually make the game lag because the balls aren't actually removed.

How can I get around this?

Comment: *"I tried to push each of the balls to an array and then destroying each ball in that array after the forEach loop, but that didn't work."* Show that, it should work.

Comment: Okay, I should have shown that. My question was already answered by you but I'll show you what I had anyway.

Comment: Great! I was just working from docs, haven't used Phaser. :-) But I was intrigued because your `forEach` didn't look like the normal `Array#forEach`, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a silly bug in Phaser, if [`Group#forEach`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Group.html#forEach) fails when you call `destroy` on one of the objects in the group during the iteration.

According to the Phaser docs, a Group has a [`filter`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Group.html#filter) function returning an [`ArraySet`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.ArraySet.html). So you could get an `ArraySet` of balls to destroy:

```
var toDestroy = balls.filter(function(ball) { return ball.x <= 800; });
```

Then `ArraySet` says it has a handy [`callAll`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.ArraySet.html#callAll) function that lets us call a function on all the entries. So we can destroy them using that:

```
toDestroy.callAll('destroy');
```

All in one:

```
balls.filter(function(ball) { return ball.x <= 800; }).callAll('destroy');
```

Or with ES2015+

```
balls.filter(ball => ball.x <= 800).callAll('destroy');
```

*(The `=>` and `<=` right near each other look funny there, but don't worry, the first one introduces an arrow function, the second is the less-than-or-equal operator.)*